# Typescript conditional type based on writability

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8

Does typescript have a way to conditionally filter a type based on property writability or readability? For example:

```
interface Foo {
  readonly x: string;
  y: string
}
type FooOptions = Writable<Foo>; // { y: string }
```

Comment: Oops, sorry! Thanks for the link. The suggestions and searches weren't showing results.